# Using select_tag multiple => true to get a combined scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am attempting to use a select_tag to create a scope of records for a report builder. One of the report items is the ability to select multiple "Status" for the report. ie. 'Approved', 'Denied' and so on.

The params go in just fine and the console reports:

```
Parameters: {"utf..., "status"=>["Pending", "Approved"]}
```

But I cannot get my controller to scope this correctly. I am currently setting scopes in the model:

```
scope :claim_status_pending, -> { where(claim_status_id: '1') }
scope :claim_status_approved, -> { where(claim_status_id: '2') }...
```

And in my controller:

```
if params[:status].present?
      new_claims_scope = Claim.none
      if params[:status].include? 'Pending'
        pending_scope = claims_scope.claim_status_pending
        new_claims_scope = pending_scope.merge(new_claims_scope)**
      elsif params[:status].include? 'Approved'
        approved_scope = claims_scope.claim_status_approved
        new_claims_scope = approved_scope.merge(new_claims_scope)
      else params[:status].include? 'Any'
        new_claims_scope = claims_scope.where("claim_status_id > ?", 0)
      end
      claims_scope = new_claims_scope
    end
```

Here is how my view is handling it:

```
= select_tag "status", options_for_select([ "Any", "Pending", "Approved", "Denied", "Under Review" ], "Any"), multiple: true
```

The "claims_scope" is already scoping down from Claims.all with .where( for other form elements. My thought was to take claims_scope and use it as the source (since it is already scoped). But I cannot get claims_scope to have two, three or more "Status". It is one or all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `scope` for multiple values:

```
scope :by_statuses, (statuses)-> { where(claim_status_id: statuses) }
```

now you can find  objects by single or multiple(array) statuses