# Rails select_tag to using scope to simple filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm still learning Rails and in my project app admin should be able to filter all holiday leave requests by status (boolean field in db) using dropdown list (approved for true, pending for false). I think I have declared everything right in my controller and model however I have no idea how to implement this to the view. I was trying to follow up [Austin's story blog](https://www.austinstory.com/rails-select-tag-and-options-for-select-explained/) and [Using select_tag multiple => true to get a combined scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44643436/using-select-tag-multiple-true-to-get-a-combined-scope) topic but still I don't figured how to do it.

leaves controller:

```
def index
 @leave = Leave.new
 @leaves = Leave.all.order(created_at: :desc).includes(:user)

 @leaves = Leave.find_by('select = ?', params[:status])
end
```

model leave.rb

```
scope :approved, -> { where(status: true) }
scope :pending, -> { where(status: false) }

belongs_to :user, optional: true
```

view index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag(action: :index) do %>
 <div class="input-group">
  <%= select_tag :status, options_for_select([['Approved', Leave.approved], ['Pending', Leave.pending]]) %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Filter' %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Why there is `Leave.new` ?

Comment: In other place, in an index view, admin creates new leave request for employee. Well... I think I shouldn't put it here(I mean in this question). Probably I'll remove this option, will see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this

```
def index
  @leave = Leave.new # as you have added it, won't affect what we want to achieve.
  #if params have status then only you've to show 
  #the selected ones otherwise you'll be showing all 
  #of them. right?
  if params[:status].present?
    @leaves = Leave.where(status: params[:status])
    #dont use find_by it will return only one record instead of array.
  else
    @leaves = Leave.includes(:user).order(created_at: :desc)
  end
end


<%= form_tag(url: admin_leaves_path, method: :get) do %>
  <div class="input-group">
    #Leave.approved will hit database from view. which is not recommended 
    #instead of that try using values which will be accessed in controller
    #via params and then you can perform actions according to it.
    <%= select_tag :status, options_for_select([['Approved', true], ['Pending', false]]) %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Filter' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for superb explanations, these are really helpful unfortunately I received an error message [param is missing or the value is empty: leave](https://imgur.com/2K9V1HO) after pushed the filter button.

Comment: why are you using `leave_params` for index page?

Comment: I don't know to be honest, my controller looks exactly the same as in the first post, I removed all from view except this form_tag but it didn't helped. Maybe you will find something in my controller? [first](https://imgur.com/MMn5UST) [second](https://imgur.com/7U52Mgn)

Comment: I've updated the answer, change `url` with index method path for leaves_controller. you can check by running `rails routes` in the terminal

Comment: what is the url you're hitting? your url should be `localhost:3000/leaves` and if you're submitting the form it should hit `index` method but it's hitting `create` method. Change the url in form_tag and let me know.

Comment: Actually it's is in `localhost:3000/admin/leaves` so I've changed `url` to the `admin_leave_path` [as in routes](https://imgur.com/NrzR6HG) but it didn't helped either, still same error.

Comment: make it `admin_leaves_path`

Comment: Yup, my mistake but it was `admin_leaves_path` instead of `admin_leave_path` at the beginning so the same error, again.

Comment: It works! I just have to restart server and use `spring stop` - after that it's working as it should be! Thank you so much for your assist.